# Reset Product URL's

Tags: php, url, product-urls

How can I reset the product URL's so that it will automatically generate new ones based on the product name.

I tried this code inside a new .php file, but that did not work:

```
<?php
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$amount = 0;
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$products = $model->getCollection();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $model->load($product->getId());
    $product->setUrlKey($model->getName())->save();
    set_time_limit();
    $amount++;
}?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow these steps Jelle.

1. back up your database

I suppose that your `url_key` attribute code for product will have `attribute_id = 97`

You can check by run this query

```
SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` where `attribute_code` = 'url_key' and `entity_type_id` = 4
```

2. run this query

`DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = 97`

3. Reindex your product URL

`Goto  System -> Index Management`

Reindex catalog URL rewrites

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
 $model->setUrlKey($product->getName())->save();
```

*Instead of*

```
 $product->setUrlKey($model->getName())->save();
```

**Also:**  add `addAttributeToSelect('name')` for add proudtc name at Collection *$products = $model->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('name');*

Change  *Mage::app();* to `Mage::app('YOUR_STORE_CODE')` or use *Mage::app('admin')*

**Note: if you have multi store then you need  to add store filter on that collection.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
require_once 'abstract.php';

class Fix_Url extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    public function run() {
        $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $products->addAttributeToSelect('name');

        foreach ($products as $product) {
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
                ->updateAttributes(array($product->getId()), array('url_key' => $product->getName()), 0);
        }
    }
}

$script = new Fix_Url();
$script->run();
```

Copy in shell subfolder (important!) and run it using:

```
php -q yourscriptname.php
php -q indexer reindexall
```

Hope will fix.